# Is an ample divisor linearly equivalent to a non-trivial effective divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In other words, if $L$ is an ample divisor, must we have $h^0(L)>0$ or can this be zero?

Comment: @TedShifrin: done. (I deleted my comment because it had a slight typo that was bothering me.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An ample divisor need not have global sections.

To see this, first note that any divisor of positive degree on a curve is ample. On the other hand, if $C$ is a curve of genus 2, and $p,q,r$ are general points on $C$, then the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_C(p+q-r)$ has no global sections.